# Why is this happening in c++ when working with OOP and pointers?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

**I was studying Object-Oriented Programming in C++, and I wrote the following code:**

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base{
    public:
    Base(string t):type(t){cout << "Base Constructor: from " + type << endl;}
    ~Base(){cout << "Base Destructor: from " + type << endl;}
    string type;
};

class Derived: public Base{
    public:
    Derived(string t):Base(t){cout << "Derived Constructor: from " + Base::type << endl;}
    ~Derived(){cout << "Derived Destructor: from " + Base::type << endl;}
};

int main(){
    Base b("base");
    Base* pb = &b;
    
    Derived d("derived");
    Derived* pd = &d;

    //delete pd; (?)
}
```

**When I run it I get the following in the terminal:**

Base Constructor: from base

Base Constructor: from derived

Derived Constructor: from derived

Derived Destructor: from derived

Base Destructor: from derived

Base Destructor: from base

**And I completly understand why.
The problem comes when I take the last comment off (I get this):**

Base Constructor: from base

Base Constructor: from derived

Derived Constructor: from derived

Derived Destructor: from derived

Base Destructor: from derived

**I don't know why I don't see the last "Base Destructor: from base" as before.
Any ideas? Thanks!**

Comment: You must declare your destructor in the base class as virtual for this to work correctly. But you also have undefined behavior here because you just manually deleted an object that was allocated on the stack. It was not yours to delete.

Comment: Oh I see, and what does the word virtual in the base destructor?

Comment: In your print statements, you can replace `+` with `<<`, as in `std::cout << "Base constructor from " << type << std::endl;`  No need for concatenation before output.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're asking what it _does_ or if you're unsure where to put it, or both. `virtual ~Base(){ /*...*/ }` makes your desctructor polymorphic, meaning that you can delete a derived object via a base pointer. Not strictly the issue here, contrary to what I said while driving-by. It was the second thing that stood out to me when I read your program, although it was the first thing I mentioned in the end.

Comment: @Ángel -- Make the `~Base()` virtual.  If you don't do this, then you cannot use your class safely in a polymorphic fashion:  `Base *pb = new Derived("derived");  delete pb;` -- that will invoke undeifned behavior if the base class destructor is not virtual.

Comment: I've done it right know thanks!

Comment: Tip: Never, *ever* `delete` something you did not `new`. Here `d` was not dynamically allocated. It cannot be deleted.